# Jitter in painting during scroll in CN1

Tags: codenameone

I want to hide a bar when I scroll down a `Container`'s content. The problem is that there is some sort of jittering at the moment when the bar gets hidden or shown up. I suppose there is a conflict of two different paint processes (one linked to the scrolling, and another one to the hide animation). How can I avoid this jittering?

screen recording (of simulator, but also happening on my smartphone):

[image: screen recording]

code snippet (hiding/showing of the bar. It's just a `ScrollListener`):

```
....
articleGallery.addScrollListener(this::onGalleryScroll);
....

private boolean ignoreEventHandling;

private void onGalleryScroll(int sX, int sY, int osX, int osY) {

    if(ignoreEventHandling) return;

    if(sY > SIGNIFICANT_VERT_SCROLL_DELTA) {
        if(!bar.isHidden()) {
            ignoreEventHandling = true;
            bar.setHidden(true);

            bar.getParent().animateLayoutAndWait(250);

            ignoreEventHandling = false;
            log.p("hiding banner due to scroll");
        }
    } else if (sY < SIGNIFICANT_VERT_SCROLL_DELTA) {

        if(bar.isHidden()) {
            ignoreEventHandling = true;
            bar.setHidden(false);

            bar.getParent().animateLayoutAndWait(250);

            ignoreEventHandling = false;
            log.p("showing up banner after scroll");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing an animate layout while the user is actively scrolling and that collides with the current logic. There is a sample of animated title area in the [Codename One Academy's free course](http://codenameone.teachable.com/).

You can also see this in this older tutorial [here](http://www.codenameone.com/blog/new-animation-manager.html). The gist of it is that you need to use a specialized title effect.

Comment: ah nice this is what I was looking for!

Comment: just one sidenode: this is working well when I use StyleAnimations. But I'm not sure how to combine it with a hiding layout animation

Comment: I show shifting layout in the academy course, there are some nuances that I explain in great detail there.